# Using If else conditions on Vectors

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having issues with the following piece of logic. Basically, i have a data frame of stocks for MS and Apple. I want to execute buy and sell conditions based on certain price comparisons. But R does not allow me to use If-Else conditions with vectors how do I overcome this scenario

```
if (mydatastocks$MS<120){
  if (mydatastocks$MS>110 & mydatastocks$MS<120){
    print("buy small")
  }else{
    print("Buy Huge")
  }
} else{
      if(mydatastocks$MS>120)
      print("Ignore")
}
```

Comment: If you have a vector of length greater than 1, use `?ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: if you are concerned with type safety, `dplyr` provides an enhanced `if_else`

Comment: @KevinArseneau, what is type safety?

Comment: @Headpoint, it means that the function checks whether or not both the `TRUE` and `FALSE` arguments are the same type and class. Think integer and double or character and factor... they can trip you up. Also `NA` of different types, it can be useful to be specific, `NA_character_` for example

Comment: @KevinArseneau thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might make the most sense to assign the order to another column in your data frame:

```
mydatastocks$order <- ifelse(mydatastocks$MS > 110 & mydatastocks$MS < 120,
                             "buy small",
                             ifelse(mydatastocks$MS <= 120, "buy huge", "ignore"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `case_when` to provide greater legibility

```
library(dplyr)

mydatastocks %>%
  mutate(message = case_when(
    MS > 110 & MS < 120 ~ "buy small",
    MS >= 120 ~ "Ignore",
    TRUE ~ "Buy Huge"
  ))
```